# Ext.calendar.panel.Panel: Cambiar posición de los botones

Tags: extjs

Estoy utilizando el Ext.calendar.panel.Panel.
He intentado cambiar la posición de los botones **'Día|Semana|Mes'** en el centro de la barra de titulo y por mucho que ponga *buttonAlign: 'center'*:

```
 views:  {
    day: { 
        label: 'Día',
        startTime: 1,
        endTime: 24,
        visibleDays: 1
        buttonAlign: 'center'
    },
```

...
No funciona, sigo teniendo los botones a la derecha.

Muchas gracias.
Salu2

Answer (score 0):

**editado**

```
views: {
    day: {
     label: 'Día',
     startTime: 1,
     endTime: 24,
     visibleDays: 1,
     buttonAlign: 'center'
    }
}
```

pero prueba a mirarte las comas que se utilizan al terminar la línea, a ver si te funciona.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, aunque las comas no han dado la solución... :-(

Comment: Cuál es el código exacto que estás utilizando Ext JS? Porque veo que en "views: {" abres la corchea pero al final del código no la cierras. podrías poner el código completo?

Comment: Hola, Es Js en ExtJs

Comment: Dentro de una view

Comment: A ver si ahora funciona, si no, te recomiendo repasar esta página https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.calendar.panel.Panel.html a ver si encuentras el problema que se te presenta. Siento no haber podido ser de más ayuda.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda. Como bien dices, estoy repasando la documentación.